# Matching time series plot with ACF plots

Tags: time-series

We have to match time series plot in the 1st row with the ACF plots in the second row. The solution for the same is given below. However , It would helpful if someone could explain the solution.[image]

Comment: Perhaps it would help get a better reply if you explained what you think the reasoning is then people might be able to help you see where you have gone wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I genuniely don't know how one can match the time series plots with the ACF plots because:
1.  ACF plots show us the correlation between the variable and its previous value. So for me to match a time series with a ACF plot , I need a intermediate scatter plot with  xaxis and the yaxis having the variable, plotted with different lags. This scatter plot will roughly tell me the correlation coefficient agaist different lags. This is how I imagine solving this.
Is there any other way around?